# Make universal function for entire App React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this function (this is just an example):

```
function highlight(el) {
  el.style.transition = "background-color 0.5s";
  el.classList.add("highlight");
  setTimeout(() => {
    el.classList.remove("highlight");
    setTimeout(() => {
      el.style.transition = "";
    }, 500);
  }, 500);
}

document.getElementsByTagName("a").addEventListener("click", function () { highlight(this) });
```

This is "universal function" that automatically binds to every `<a>` on page onload, it is short (only several lines long) and I can add or remove it in seconds (the code on pages are intact).

What is the best approach to implement it in React App?

Course I knew the obvious way, with the manual add of onClick to every `<a>` in every component on page with setState logic, but ... it kinda sucks

I'm new to React, maybe someone can point me to the right direction

How I can implement this logic on every page(every component that has `<a>`) efficiently, with the ability to easy remove it if it is no longer needed?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the way I see it, if you want the *react way*, then you would want to create a presentation component with the defined behavior and use that component instead of .
In fact, that would actually be a perfect fit for a presentational react component.
Then, if you need to implement any changes, you would do them inside that component.

You could alternatively add vanilla js to the index page but that kinda misses the whole point of react.

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently developing this application then the best approach is to create a small tiny component for it. For example you can create a component `HighligtedAnchor` and can implement the stylistic features in it directly.

Secondly, if you directly want to handle a lot of anchors then the most appropriate place would be the root of your application that is usually `App.js` or you can write it down in the `index.html` as well if you really want to move forward with the plane js approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at for something like good old [`jquery live`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) you can't do that in reactjs.
The best thing you can do is to create a custom component that wraps the `<a>` tag. And use your custom component everywhere you would use regular `<a>` tag.